# Dictionaries: added value to one key also gets added to other keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a big excel file with 36352 rows, containing information on burglaries. Each row contains a date and the name of the municipality where the event occurred. I'm trying to convert this dataset into a calendar map for each municipality, stating how many burglaries there were on every day of the year.

I first created a calendar map (dictionary), where the date is the key and the value is the number of burglaries (initialised as 0): `{day1: 0, day2: 0}`.

Next I made another dictionary, where the keys are the names of the municipalities and the value is the calendar dictionary.

E.g.:

```
Dictionary['New York'] = {day1: 0, day2: 0, day3: 0}
```

This initialization works fine.

Next step I took is to go through my dataset row by row (written to content_split), took the name of the municipality and the date of the event as keys, and added 1 to the value:

```
Dictionary[name-in-column-14-of-excel-file][day-of-event] += 1
```

I wrote this as a loop:

```
for k in range(1,len(excelfile)): #for all rows in the excel file
    # datetime.datetime(year,month,day)
    d = datetime.datetime(int(content_split[k][9]),int(content_split[k][8]),int(content_split[k][7]))
    # Dictionary[name-of-municipality][timestamp-in-utc] += 1
    Municipality_dict[content_split[k][14]][calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())] += 1
```

If I then look into the calendar dictionary for 1 municipality, I get very high numbers (176 burglaries for 1 day in 1 city) and the calendar maps for different municipalities are identical. It thus seems as if my municipality key is not working, but I have no clue way.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit for how I created the dictionaries:

```
# Open map containing the days
with open('days.csv') as f1:
  days_temp = f1.readlines()

alldays = []

# Get dd;mm;yy format to [dd, mm, yy] format
for day in days_temp:
   alldays.append(day.strip().split(';'))

Timestamp = {}

# Convert days into UTC codes
for i in range(len(alldays)):
d = datetime.datetime(int(alldays[i][2]),int(alldays[i][1]),int(alldays[i][0]))

# dictionary[UTC-time-code] = 0 (no burglaries occurred)
Timestamp[calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())] = 0

# Open file with names of municipalities
with open('file2.csv') as f2:
    municipalities_temp = f2.readlines()

municipalities_dict = {}  

# dictionary[name-of-municipality] = calendar
for instance in municipalities_temp:
    municipalities_dict[instance.strip()] = Timestamp
```

Comment: How did you *create* those dictionaries? You are sharing references, and have just *one* dictionary, not separate objects.

Comment: If you did something like `d = {'day1': 0, ...}; M_D['New York'] = d; M_D['Boston'] = d; ...`, you would see the results you are getting.

Comment: I edited my original post. I didn't understand the 'sharing references' part at first, but now with ErlVolton's reply, I understand what you mean. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like when you create your second dictionary where the keys are municipality names, each key is getting assigned as a reference to the same dictionary.  See the following sample:

```
>>> test = {"x":"y"}
>>> test2 = test
>>> test["x"] = "foo"
>>> test2
{'x': 'foo'}
>>>
```

Note that test2["x"] changed to foo when test changed because test2 is a reference to test, and not it's own dictionary.  Solution?

```
import copy

template_dict = {day1: 0, day2: 0, day3: 0}
Dictionary['New York'] = copy.deepcopy(template_dict)
```

Comment: @Jolien. Also, instead of copying you can use `template_dict = lambda: {day1: 0, day2: 0, day3: 0}` then use it as `Dictionary['New York'] = template_dict()` (assuming those keys should be 'day1', 'day2' and 'day3')